# Argument of type 'this' not assignable to parameter 'Construct'

Tags: node.js, aws-cdk

I am trying to call a lambda function into a 'sample app' stack and it is giving me an error because I am trying to pass it a parameter of 'this'.

Here is my lambda function

```
export async function handler(event) {
    console.log("request:", JSON.stringify(event, undefined, 2));
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" },
        body: `Hello, CDK! You've hit ${event.path}\n`
    };
};
```

Here is the 'app' calling that function

```
//import sns = require('@aws-cdk/aws-sns');
//import subs = require('@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions');
//import sqs = require('@aws-cdk/aws-sqs');
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
import lambda = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda');

//Exports class from other file much like a function

export class CdkWorkshopStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) { 
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Describes an AWSLambda Resource
    const hello = new lambda.Function (this, 'HelloHandler', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_8_10,    //execution environment
      code: lambda.Code.asset('lambda'),   // code loaded from the "lambda" directory
      handler: 'hello.handler'                // file is "hello", function is "handler"
    });
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
lib/cdk-workshop-stack.ts:31:39 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'.
  Type 'CdkWorkshopStack' is not assignable to type 'Construct'.
    Types of property 'node' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("/Users/aroe/cdk-workshop/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct").ConstructNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/aroe/cdk-workshop/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct").ConstructNode'.
        Types have separate declarations of a private property 'host'.

31     const hello = new lambda.Function(this, 'HelloHandler', {
                                         ~~~~

[1:24:08 PM] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

And finally I am using Node version v13.3.0

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The construct definition looks right to me. That error can occur if the various cdk modules aren't all at the same version; see [Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3416) for one example of that. Try running `npm update`; see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I got the error after installing @aws-cdk/aws-lambda. My CDK version was 1.22.0 while the recently installed lambda package was 1.23.0

After installing the corresponding lambda 1.22.0 the issue was fixed

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error because the installed version for `@aws-cdk/aws-lambda` and `@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions` was different,

while `aws-sns-subscriptions` has a dependency on `aws-lambda` of the same version.

[image]

when I downgraded `@aws-cdk/aws-lambda` version the error is gone!

you can also update all `aws-cdk` packages to have the same version.

Comment: This resolved my issue.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do that?

Answer (score 7):

In my case I even though I had used the `cdk init app --language=typescript` the project bootstrapped with the old legacy `aws-cdk` library.

So when I started using Typescript libraries from the `@aws-cdk` namespaced packages, I received this error.

So I had to replace all references to `Stack`, `Construct`, etc. from the `@aws-cdk/core`:

```js
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as sqs from '@aws-cdk/aws-sqs';
import * as lambda from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda'
import { SqsEventSource } from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-sources';

export class WorkerCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // example resource
    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'WorkerQueue', {
      queueName: 'WorkerQueue',
    });

    // processor function
    const processor = new lambda.Function(this, 'QueueProcessor', {
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambda'),
      handler: 'processor.handler',
      functionName: 'QueueProcessor',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
    });

    // map processor to queue
    processor.addEventSource(new SqsEventSource(queue, {
      batchSize: 10, // default
      reportBatchItemFailures: true, // default to false
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe they messed up the template like that.

Answer (score 4):

change
`import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';`

to
`import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';`

in bin/something_cdk.ts file

Comment: AWS's own CDK Primer tutorial is screwed up. The tutorial video and isntructions assume v1 dependencies, but the test files Amazon provides contain a mix of v1 and v2 dependencies. Your answer got me on the right track to fix Amazon's tutorial. Thank you!

Comment: Feels great to be of help !! @kookaburra

Comment: This is how I fixed it

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
```

instead of using:

```
import * as ec2 from '@aws-cdk/aws-ec2';
import * as iam from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';
```

Getting all the modules from ***aws-cdk-lib***, thus from the same version

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by simply ignoring the 'this' error and running the lambda anyway. I do not believe it would have worked if it was an actual node/JS program. However, when using CDK native TypeScript it babies you a lot.

Comment: can you plz share what you did put after removing this coz I am also getting same issue but after removing "this" getting lib/cdk-stack.ts:183:52 - error TS2345: Argument of type '"playerlogsBucket"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'.

183         const playerlogsBucket = new s3.CfnBucket( "playerlogsBucket", {
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 1):

**Just changing**

```
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";

import * as apigw from "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway";

import lambda from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda"

import dynamodb from "@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb"
```

**To**

```
const lambda = require ('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda');

const dynamodb= require('@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb');

const cdk=require('@aws-cdk/core');

const apigw=require('@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway');
```

**worked for me**